# Gnome shell transparency issue with a theme

Tags: gnome, command-line

just installed Gnome Shell and started theming it, and "le wild gray stripe appeared" on the panel, doesn't matter what theme I use, except for the default as I guess it doesn't use transparency, anyone recognise this?

[image]

Comment: switch to default shell theme
and logout and return

Comment: No dice, still a grey bar on the upper half of the panel

Comment: Disable all gnome extensions including user themes extension from gnome-tweak-tool
and enable the required extensions one by one

Comment: Nope, if I just enable theme switch or autohide its still there.
So it's probably not a themeing issue, rather its with gnome/ubuntu itself.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that.